# GOPATH and GOBIN set and exported in Fedora but still not installing program

Tags: go, fedora, fedora-21

I have GO installed on a Fedora 21 laptop and I setup GOPATH and GOBIN, but it for some reason is not letting me install my go Programs.

```
pred@computer01 [20:03:02] ~  
$ echo $GOPATH
/home/pred/Documents/GO
pred@computer01 [20:03:11] ~  
$ echo $GOBIN
/home/pred/Documents/GO/bin
pred@computer01 [20:03:15] ~  
$ cd $GOPATH
pred@computer01 [20:03:21] ~/Documents/GO  
$ go install src/github.com/pred3/go_helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.go 
go install: no install location for .go files listed on command line (GOBIN not set)
pred@computer01 [20:03:32] ~/Documents/GO  
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/pred/Documents/GO/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/pred/Documents/GO"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/golang"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

What else should I be doing to get this to work?

--EDIT--

Issuing the following command as stated below also gave errors.

```
pred@computer1 [21:22:51] ~/Documents/GO  
$ go install src/github.com/pred3/go_helloworld/helloworld
can't load package: package src/github.com/predatorian3/go_helloworld/helloworld: cannot find package "src/github.com/pred3/go_helloworld/helloworld" in any of:
    /usr/lib/golang/src/src/github.com/pred3/go_helloworld/helloworld (from $GOROOT)
    /home/pred/Documents/GO/src/src/github.com/pred3/go_helloworld/helloworld (from $GOPATH)
```

However, I did not have `package main` at the beginning of the go file I was trying to install. Once I changed it to `package main` it worked. I'm not sure why I couldn't use a different package name though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[go install](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) expects a package as argument (see [Description of package lists](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_package_lists) for more detailed explanation). In your case it probably should be

```
go install github.com/pred3/go_helloworld/helloworld
```

assuming that `$GOPATH/src/github.com/pred3/go_helloworld/helloworld` directory exists and `$GOPATH/src/github.com/pred3/go_helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.go` starts with `package main`

The following commands will do the same:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/pred3/go_helloworld/helloworld
go intsall
```

Comment: Changing the package name worked. I couldn't use a custom name, but `package main` worked. For some reason, I get an error when I don't include the main go file in the go install command. I'll post the error in the OP.

Comment: Custom package names are used for libraries only (i.e. packages that are used by other libraries or commands). Applications (that are compiled to binaries) should always use `package main`